# How is SQL Server mapping my server using a "." as the server name?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at an existing configuration. One SQL Server and I can connect like this:

`myServer (SQL Server 1.1.1.2 - personal)`

`Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;`

or like this:

`. (SQL Server 1.1.1.2 - personal)`

`Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;`

What I don't understand is how this is setup to have the "." map to the server name "myServer"?

I tried this on a local instance of SQL Server that I have setup and the "." doesn't map to the local instance of SQL Server that I have, so I'm assuming there is some sort of mapping done on the server I'm working with?

Nothing useful in ODBC 32/64 bit client either. Does anyone have any advice as to how this is setup?

Comment: `.` is a synonym for `localhost`.

Comment: So on my local machine, I have an instance of SQL Server that's "MyLaptop\SQLEXPRESS". Why can't I do the same and connect with a "." as the server name?

Also, I can't connect as "localhost" on my personal machine, but I can connect as "MyLaptop\SQLEXPRESS" just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Because you would need `.\SQLEXPRESS` a it's a named instance. `YourOtherServer` won't work either, it would have to be `YourOtherServer\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @Larnu Thank you